# jQuery function not working for IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, function

I have this part of the function :

```
$jQ('.product-collateral .product-tabs li').each(function(index){
            $jQ(this).attr('id', $jQ(this).find('h3').attr('class'));
            if(index === 0) 
                $jQ(this).addClass('active'); 
        });
```

Is there any reason why would this not work with internet explorer 9?

I'v spent quite a lot of time now trying to figure it out and have no idea.

Thank you for your advice in advance.

Dom

-- Sorry, this is the html

```
<div class="product-collateral">
    <div class="tab">
      <h3 class="product_tabs_agenda">Tab 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_agenda_contents">
      <p>Tab1 Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <h3 class="product_tabs_terms">Terms and Conditions</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_terms_contents">
      <p>Some terms and conditions</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the full java function.

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > $jQ('.product-collateral .tab h3').wrapAll('<ul class="product-tabs"></ul>').wrap('<li></li>');
$jQ('.product-collateral .product-tabs li').each(function(index) {
    $jQ(this).attr('id', $jQ(this).find('h3').attr('class'));
    if (index == 0) $jQ(this).addClass('active');
});
//<![CDATA[
Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
    initialize: function(selector) {
        var self = this;
        $$(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
    },

    initTab: function(el) {
        el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
        if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
            this.showContent(el);
        }
        el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
    },

    showContent: function(a) {
        var li = $(a.parentNode),
            ul = $(li.parentNode);
        ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el) {
            var contents = $(el.id + '_contents');
            if (el == li) {
                el.addClassName('active');
                contents.show();
            } else {
                el.removeClassName('active');
                contents.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs');
//]]>
< /script>
```

Sorry, I think it was my frustration about this "thing"

Thank you

Comment: is this working in other browsers?

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Errors? Unexpected behavior? What part of the code doesn't work, or none of it?

Comment: could you please provide more code? like the html in question, and what specifically is not working...

Comment: YEs, this works fine in any other browsert

Comment: Works fine with me: http://jsfiddle.net/tYTu3/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Make sure this is defined beforehand.
$jQ does not have any value in the code you provided.

```
$jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Is probably missing. This must be defined before you call the alias.

Comment: Also, please use _ or - consistently in your class names.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, Ive tried that. Still nothing. The strangest thing is that this script is working fine in IE7 and 8 mode but not in 9. I am so lost here